# custom post type categories not display checkboxes but text fileds

Tags: wordpress

Why when I create a custom post type called profiles and and custom categories for profiles, do I not get the standard display of standard catergories instead I get a text box to say to seperate catergories by a comma in the profile admin page not the default checkbox display so my user can select the categories im using the

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you [create a **Categories taxonomy**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) and not a **Tags one**. See the `hierarchical = TRUE` for *categories* or `hierarchical = FALSE` for *tags*.